# Ubuntu starting in low resolution and keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: boot, keyboard, mouse, resolution, freeze

I just installed Ubuntu on my 2010 Mac mini, (2.1GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB RAM) and at first it worked fine. Then, after turning off the computer, when I powered it on again it logged in and displayed my desktop, but the resolution is really low and the mouse and keyboard stopped doing anything.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try including nomodeset as a boot option in grub. From the main grub bootloader press 'e' to edit the boot parameters. Find where it reads:

```
quiet splash
```

Edit to look like this:

```
quiet splash nomodeset
```

Hopefully this will solve your resolution issue and prevent the crash. If so, try changing your graphics driver from the 'Additional Software' app and reboot.